# python datatypes - int to format

Tags: r, python-3.x, format

This question might look silly, but please bear with me as I am a beginner in Python scripting.

I have been working on machine learning using R and Python.
In R we have datatype called as format (which takes predefined values - ex: 1 2 3).
Is there any datatype in Python which is corresponding to format ?

I am working on a logistic regression problem, all the attributes are in int64, I need to convert some of the attributes to format ..?

Lets take the below example: In R this is my code

```
test = c(1,2,3,3,1,3,2,1,3,2)
test = as.factor(test)
```

Output will be as below

```
test = c(1,2,3,3,1,3,2,1,3,2)
str(test)
# num [1:10] 1 2 3 3 1 3 2 1 3 2
test = as.factor(test)
str(test)
# Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3 3 1 3 2 1 3 2
```

In Python how could we do the above operation (Converting from numeric data type to factors/levels).

Comment: This is a bit vague. I suggest you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example, then edit your question.

Comment: I apologise for the spelling mistakes...

Comment: Spelling is not the problem. Please read those links, thinking about making a problem reproducible. By "reproducible", I mean being able to reproduce the problem on my computer given the data and code you provide in your question. Since you've provided nothing -- and it is unclear what you mean by *"we have datatype called as format"* -- then there is nothing we can do but guess. (Or convince you to improve your question so that we can help you.)

Comment: Lets take the below example:
In R this is my code
 test = c(1,2,3,3,1,3,2,1,3,2)
 str(test)
 test = as.factor(test)
 str(test)
 
 Output will be as below
 > test = c(1,2,3,3,1,3,2,1,3,2)
 > str(test)
   num [1:10] 1 2 3 3 1 3 2 1 3 2
 > test = as.factor(test)
 > str(test)
   Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 2 3 3 1 3 2 1 3 2
 > 

In Python how could we do the above operation (Converting from numeric data type to factors/levels) ?

Comment: I suggested an edit that includes what you just said in the comment. It belongs in the question for two reasons: code (especially multi-line) can be very hard to interpret in comments; and especially when the comment-count goes high, comments will be skipped. That last comment provides significant context to your question, as now I infer that your `format` is a variable storing ordinal or categorical data (was not clear before).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a type conversion mechanism you can use astype in numpy

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 2.5])
>>> x
array([ 1. ,  2. ,  2.5])

>>> x.astype(int)
```

Please check the below link for more documentation on astype.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html